# Compiler warning when using `%*s` with `printf`

Tags: c, warnings, printf

When I compile the following:

```
printf("%*s",lengths[i],row[i]);
```

I get this warning:

```
4.0.c:407: warning: field width should have type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type 
‘long  unsigned int’
```

lengths is declared as: `unsigned long *lengths;`.

I tried to solve the problem but to no avail.
Adding this,

```
printf("%*lu",(unsigned long)lengths[i],row[i]);
```

I get no more warnings but the code doesn't work as it should.

Thank you Vera

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to display? And can you show the declaration for both `lengths` and `rows`?

Comment: You may want to edit the title of this question...the compiler sees the format string as a constant and will never issue a warning based on the format string.  If you ever get a warning or error compiling a `printf` you should debug the rest of the function call first.

Comment: @keith.layne: I think I am to blame for the title, but the title of a question does not necessarily have to relate to the answer, but in fact what somebody with a similar problem might *search for*. The point is that `%*s` expected an `int` which was not apparent for the user of `printf`.

Comment: @bitmask Okay, I wasn't thinking that way, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Cast it to an `int`:

```
printf("%*s", (int) lengths[i], row[i]);
```

Comment: @TomZych, that was my mistake.  I misunderstood your (and pmg's) answer initially.  I've tried to undo the downvote, but it's preventing me from doing so.

Comment: @jamessan: It doesn't let you reverse a vote after a few minutes unless the posting is edited. I'll edit mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to print it:

```
printf("%*s", (int) lengths[i], row[i]);
```

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#Format_placeholders:

> ***** - Causes `printf` to pad the output until it is n characters wide, where n is an **integer value** stored in the a function argument just preceding that represented by the modified type. For example `printf("%*d", 5, 10)` will result in "10" being printed with a width of 5.

So unless `lengths` is being used for something else also that needs it to be an `unsigned long` I would suggest to turn it into `int *lengths`.

Comment: Because no one said `row` (not `rows`) was a number. The original code implies it's a string.

Comment: @Tom Zych: Ah thanks, was a bit too quick there - edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the value isn't larger than `INT_MAX` and cast it to `int` to agree with the asterisk in the `printf` conversion specifier

```
printf("%*s", (int)lengths[i], row[i]);
```

See 7.19.6.1/5 in the [C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> ... an **int** argument supplies the field width or precision ...

Comment: It's a field width. If it were greater than `INT_MAX` you'd have several million spaces coming out before your data, which is a rather more serious bug.

Comment: If it were greater than `INT_MAX` the cast invokes an implementation-defined conversion which could turn 65536 to -1 ... and printing a field with a width of `-1` makes the output left-justified with a width of 1: very very different than a right-justified field of 65536 chars or an error message.

Comment: And why did this get downvoted? Someone's being abusive I think.

Comment: I suppose your way is more robust, though it begs the question of what the program should do if it is > `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, but don't worry ... I may have ninja-edited away the downvote reason (maybe failure to include a quote from the Standard, or a typo) lol

Comment: We both got downvoted for no apparent reason, that's why I phrased it that way.

Answer (score 0):

use like this... `printf("%*ul", (int) lengths[i], row[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand what you're trying to do, you want to print `row[i]` as a string with a field width specified by `lengths[i]`?

If that's the case, you need to cast the value of `lengths[i]` to `int`:

```
printf("%*s", (int) lengths[i], row[i]);
```

If that's *not* what you're trying to do, then you need to update your question with more information.